# Public or Shared Assembly? Which one is correct?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am confused that what is the correct terminolgy to use. I've heard that four types of Assemblies are ther in .Net like,

1. Private
2. Shared/Public
3. Static
4. Dynamic

My Question is what is the perfect/correct/legal term to use **Shared** or **Public** ??
Please reply if anyone had an idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are three types of assemlies 1.private 2. public/shared 3.satelite/global.

**Shared Assembly or Public Assembly** - A shared assembly has version constraint. It is stored in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC). GAC is a repository of shared assemblies maintained by the .NET runtime. It is located at C:\Windows\Assembly OR C:\Winnt\Assembly. The shared assemblies may be used by many applications. To make an assembly a shared assembly, it has to be strongly named. In order to share an assembly with many applications, it must have a strong name.

so shared or public are similar